# Angular 14 Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js) and (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js)

Tags: angular, angular-material, custom-theme, angular14upgrade

Theme selected : custom

Error:
SassError: @use rules must be written before any other rules.

╷
39 │ @use '@angular/material' as mat;

╵
src\custom-theme.scss 39:1  root stylesheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBvhZ.png)

Comment: Can you bring more detail and showing your `package.json` and full of error by text (not captured image)

Answer (score -1):

In file :   src\custom-theme.scss

Check for the line :
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

In my file were 2. There must be only one so delete the rest